# MVC 5 ViewModel with EditorTemplate of a enumerable property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to find the best correct way to do the following:

I have a ViewModel for a character editor called CharacterViewModel. This CharacterViewModel is populated with a Character object, a list of available ability scores a character can have, which are in another table.

I created an edit template for the drop down, and I'm trying to find a way to recuperate the list of edited abilities. I can't seem to get them back on the controller.

Here is the ViewModel code:

```
    public class CharacterViewModel : DbContext
    {
            public Character Character { get; set; }

            [UIHint("CharacterAbilityScores")]
            public IEnumerable<CharacterAbilityScore> CharacterAbilityScores { get; set; }

            public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AbilityScoresSelectList { get; set; }

            public IEnumerable<AbilityModifiersAndBonusSpellDTO> AbilityModifiersAndBonusSpellDTO { get; set; }

            public CharacterViewModel()
                : base("name=CharacterModels")
            {
            }
    }
```

Here is the controller code for populating the ViewModel:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        Character character = db.Characters.Find(id);
        var model = new CharacterViewModel();
        model.Character = character;
        model.CharacterAbilityScores = character.CharacterAbilityScores;

        // Creating the list of ability scores for the view            
        model.AbilityScoresSelectList = from amabs in db.AbilityModifiersAndBonusSpells
                                        select new SelectListItem()
                                        {
                                            Value = amabs.score.ToString(),
                                            Text = amabs.score.ToString()
                                        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

The edit method signature in the controller (the CharacterAbilityScores property and the other complex ones are always empty on the return trip):

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(CharacterViewModel characterViewModel)
```

Here is the related code in the edit view:

```
    @model CampaignManager.Models.CharacterViewModel
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
            <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CharacterAbilityScores, new { AbilityScoresSelectList = Model.AbilityScoresSelectList })
            </div>
    }
```

And finally, the EditorTemplate:

```
    @model IEnumerable<CampaignManager.Entities.CharacterAbilityScore>

    <table>
    @foreach (var abilityScore in Model)
    {
            <tr>
                    <td>@abilityScore.Ability.Abbreviation</td>
                    <td>
                            @{
                            if (ViewData["AbilityScoresSelectList"] != null)
                            {
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(z => abilityScore);
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(z => abilityScore.AbilityId);
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => abilityScore.AbilityId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["AbilityScoresSelectList"], dropDownHTMLOptions);
                            }
                    }
                    </td>
            <tr>
    }
    </table>
```

I've tried many different HiddenFor tricks, storing the whole collection, storing different id's... I'm a bit lost in there I'll admit. Maybe I'm doing this all wrong and I need another approach?

**UPDATE**

Here is the model for the CharacterAbilityScore entity:

```
public partial class CharacterAbilityScore
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CharacterId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int AbilityId { get; set; }

    public int AbilityScore { get; set; }

    public virtual Ability Ability { get; set; }

    public virtual AbilityModifiersAndBonusSpell AbilityModifiersAndBonusSpell { get; set; }

    public virtual Character Character { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EditorFor()` is designed to wok with collection where the `EditorTemplate` is the `type` in the collection (in your case you have made the `EditorTemplate`'s model a collection (not the `type`) and are then giving each element a duplicate `id` attribute (invalid html) and duplicate `name` attributes (which cant be bound to a collection).

Change the template (`Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/CharacterAbilityScore.cshtml`) to:

```
@model CampaignManager.Entities.CharacterAbilityScore
<tr>
  <td>@Html.DisplatFor(m => m.Ability.Abbreviation)</td>
  <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AbilityId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["AbilityScoresSelectList"])</td>
</tr>
```

and in the main view

```
@model CampaignManager.Models.CharacterViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <table>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CharacterAbilityScores, new { AbilityScoresSelectList = Model.AbilityScoresSelectList })
  </table>
}
```

Side notes:

1. You have not posted the model for `CharacterAbilityScore` so a have
   assumed it contains properties `Abbreviation` (for display only) and
   `AbilityId` (associated with the dropdown).
2. You can not use `@Html.HiddenFor()` on a complex object (the value
   will be the `.ToString()` output of the object) and having
   `@Html.HiddenFor()` for the same property as the dropdown (and
   located before `@Html.DropDownListFor()`) means that you will bind
   to the hidden input on post back (i.e. the original value, not the
   selected value from the dropdown)
3. I also recommend your view models do not derive from `DbContext`.
   The purpose of a view model is to define the properties you want to
   display/edit in the view

Comment: Thanks for the comments! The problem that CharacterAbilityScores is a list, many ability scores for one character. So, if I pass the list to the template, I don't have access to a general ID unless I loop.

I guess I should loop in the main page?

Comment: I know `CharacterAbilityScores` is a collection, which is why you need to do it as I have stated. I am not sure what you mean by the _"general ID"_ - but you can always pass additional properties using `additionalViewData` as you have done for the `SelectList`. You need to post the models so I can understand exactly what your doing (I just had to make some assumptions). In any case, why would you need to pass the main models ID to the child object? If its a hidden input in the main view, it will be posted back and you have access to it in the controller.

Comment: I added the model. And if I change my code like you asked, there's a discrepancy from the model passed from the main view to the template, since in your example the template receives a unique entity and the main view passes a collection. That's why I asked if in your example I should loop in the main view.

Comment: You can use a loop, but then you will have problems with using `@Html.DropDownListFor()` - the first option will always be selected no matter what the value of the property is (it's a know issue and the only work around is to initialize a new `SelectList` in each iteration). But the `EditorTemplate` will work - `EditorFor()` accepts collections and is smart enough to render each individual item in that collection so long as the name of the template matches the name of the model.

Comment: I cannot see any thing in your code suggesting that you need to pass a _"general ID"_ to the template, but you really need to be creating view models for your child objects - e.g. `CharacterAbilityScoreViewModel` with only the properties you need to display/edit, and `CharacterViewModel` would then have property `public IEnumerable<CharacterAbilityScoreViewModel> CharacterAbilityScores { get; set; }`. Also make sure you remove the `[UIHint("CharacterAbilityScores")]` from the property.

Comment: Yes, I'll do that, and I forgot to rename the template, now that it's renamed (removed the pluralized), it works since it's considered a template for a single object. Thanks for your help!